# How do I jump while on the box 0 in my code

Tags: javascript, web

My case for the jump is for player.velocity.y to be 0
in the log it is zero but I can't jump while on the boxes
i asked 5 different friends but no one helped me as thery had the sdame ideas as me on how to fix
nothing seems to work

I was expecting for player.velocity.y to become -18

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<head></head>

<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>

<script src="js/classes/Player.js"></script>
<script src="js/classes/events.js"></script>
<script src="js/classes/map.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
body{
    background:#001f79
}
canvas{
    background-color: #386bc7;
}
```

These codes above are not really important

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    switch(event.key){
        case 'w':
            if (player.velocity.y == 0) {
                player.velocity.y -= 18;
            }         
    }
});

function update() {
    player.velocity.y += gravityAcceleration;

    player.position.x += player.velocity.x;
    player.position.y += player.velocity.y;

    if (player.position.y >= canvas.height - player.height) {
        player.position.y = canvas.height - player.height;
        player.velocity.y = 0;
    }
}
```

There might be a bug in events

```
let rows=10
let cols=30
let boxH=75,boxW=75
const velocity=10
let position=0
let eRow=0,eCol=0


function bgD(){
  c.fillStyle = '#4178c8'
        c.fillRect((boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow, boxW, boxH);
        c.fillStyle = "#3c6bbd";
        c.fillRect((boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+4, boxW-8, boxH-8);
}

//let cols=100

let maparr =[
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],
];

function drawM() {
    for(eRow=0; eRow<rows; eRow++) {
      for(eCol=0; eCol<cols; eCol++) {
        if(maparr[eRow][eCol] === 1) {
          c.fillStyle = '#4178c8'
          c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow, boxW, boxH);
          c.fillStyle = "#3c6bbd";
          c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+4, boxW-8, boxH-8);
        } else if(maparr[eRow][eCol] === 0) {
            c.fillStyle = "white";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow, boxW, boxH);
            c.fillStyle = "black";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+4, boxW-8, boxH-8);           
            c.fillStyle = "#1b1b1b";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+16, boxW-8, boxH-20);
            c.fillStyle = "#404040";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+28, boxW-8, boxH-32);
            c.fillStyle = "#6f6f6f";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+40, boxW-8, boxH-44);
            c.fillStyle = "#a4a4a4";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+52, boxW-8, boxH-56);
            c.fillStyle = "white";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+64, boxW-8, boxH-68);
            if (player.position.x >= position+(boxW*eCol) && player.position.x <= position+(boxW*eCol)+boxW){
                if (player.sides.bottom <= boxH*eRow && player.sides.bottom+player.velocity.y >= boxH*eRow)
                  {
                    player.velocity.y=0
                  }
            }
        } else if(maparr[eRow][eCol] === 2) {
            c.fillStyle = '#4178c8'
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow, boxW, boxH);
            c.fillStyle = "#3c6bbd";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+4, boxW-8, boxH-8);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow+60, boxW, boxH-60);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+48, boxW-8, boxH-48);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+10, boxH*eRow+36, boxW-20, boxH-36);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+15, boxH*eRow+24, boxW-30, boxH-24);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+20, boxH*eRow+12, boxW-40, boxH-12);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+26, boxH*eRow, boxW-52, boxH);
            c.fillStyle = "black";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+30, boxH*eRow+4, boxW-60, boxH-8);
            c.fillStyle = "#1b1b1b";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+24, boxH*eRow+16, boxW-48, boxH-20);
            c.fillStyle = "#404040";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+19, boxH*eRow+28, boxW-38, boxH-32);
            c.fillStyle = "#6f6f6f";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+14, boxH*eRow+40, boxW-28, boxH-44);
            c.fillStyle = "#a4a4a4";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+8, boxH*eRow+52, boxW-16, boxH-56);
            c.fillStyle = "white";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+64, boxW-8, boxH-68);
        } else if(maparr[eRow][eCol] === 3) {
            c.fillStyle = '#4178c8'
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow, boxW, boxH);
            c.fillStyle = "#3c6bbd";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+4, boxW-8, boxH-8);
            c.fillStyle = "red";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol), boxH*eRow+52, boxW,23);
            c.fillStyle = "black";
            c.fillRect(position+(boxW*eCol)+4, boxH*eRow+56, boxW-8,15);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function updateM(){
      position -= velocity
  }
```

The script here returned 0 on the plkayer.velocity.y

```
class Player{
    constructor(){
        this.position = {
            x: 300,
            y: 675,
        }
        
        this.velocity = {
            y: 0,
        }

        this.width = 75
        this.height = 75
        this.sides = {
            bottom: this.position.y + this.height,
            right: this.position.x + this.width,
            top: this.position.y,
        }
        this.gravity = 2
    }

    draw() {
        //base
        c.fillStyle = '#11dde2'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x,this.position.y,this.width,this.height)
        c.fillStyle = 'black'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+3,this.position.y+3,this.width-6,this.height-6)
        c.fillStyle = '#fcbc04'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+4,this.position.y+4,this.width-8,this.height-8)
        //face
        c.fillStyle = 'black'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+15,this.position.y+15,16,16)
        c.fillStyle = '#11dde2'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+16,this.position.y+16,14,14)
        c.fillStyle = 'black'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+45,this.position.y+15,16,16)
        c.fillStyle = '#11dde2'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+46,this.position.y+16,14,14)
        c.fillStyle = 'black'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+15,this.position.y+45,47,14)
        c.fillStyle = '#11dde2'
        c.fillRect (this.position.x+16,this.position.y+46,45,12)
    }

    

    update() {
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y
        this.sides.bottom = this.position.y + this.height
      if (this.sides.bottom + this.velocity.y  < canvas.height) {
      this.velocity.y += 1
        
      }  
      else this.velocity.y = 0
    }
}
```

there is nothing wrong in the index I think

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = 1425
canvas.height = 750

const background = {
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    }
}



const player = new Player()

const keys = {
    w: {
        pressed: false,
    },
}



function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.clearRect(background.position.x,background.position.y,canvas.width,canvas.height)


    player.velocity.x = 0
    drawM()
    updateM()
    player.update()
    player.draw()

}

animate()
```